# Converting decimal number to IEEE format

Tags: numerics

Hello stackoverflow community, Today I want to know if my solution for this question is correct or not , and if it is not please tell me why and what is the correctness of it and thanks in advance.

The question : Convert the decimal number 1.5 x 2^-126 to IEEE single-precision format.

My answer is : 00000000110000000000000000000000 , where :-

*sign-bit = 0 (positive floating point number)

*Exponent = -126+Bias = -126+127=+1 = 00000001

*Mantissa bits = 10000000000000000000000 (1.5 in decimal = 1.1 in normalized binary form)

Comment: why shouldn't you write a program which display the number in binary format

Comment: just to check your work go here: http://www.binaryconvert.com/

Comment: Thaanks a lott!!